# Power BI Dax for the Products sold together

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to findout which 5 products combination are brought most by the customers,

This is the dataset, orderID doesn't have a unique values.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDlF7.png)

I am actually trying to create a similar chart like in the picture, so could you please help me?
[image]

Comment: Probably need to use Python in Power Query for this.  See, eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDV0Zh6HDGc

Comment: Thank you for the reply!!! is there any possibility to achieve  this by using DAX since I don't know python? :)

Comment: Maybe a basket analysis pattern may be a start, https://www.daxpatterns.com/basket-analysis/

Answer (score 0):

Dummy Table I created -
[image]

There are two ways to do this -

1. Using Power Query Group BY -

   `#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Order ID"}, {{"Sum of order quantity", each List.Sum([Quantity]), type nullable number}, {"Products combined", each Text.Combine([#"Product "],","), type nullable text}}),`

[image]

2. Using dax, we can't use Group By function here as in dax Group By only applies on numeric columns but we have Products as well that is text column. So we can use Summarizecolumns.

> `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Table'[OrderID],"products",concatenatex(VALUES('Table'[Product ]),'Table'[Product ]," "),"Sum of order quantity",SUMx(VALUES('Table'[Quantity]),'Table'[Quantity]))`

[image]